# Can I get sued for putting bleach in someone's drink?

Tags: health, civil-legal-system, food

I had a slushie order, and we were out of water. There was a bottle of clear liquid, which I mistook as water. I put in around 3 ounces. Later, My boss informed me that the clear liquid under the water can was not back-up water, but BLEACH. The problem was that they informed me AFTER I had already served the customer! Can either I or the restaurant get sued for this?  ( I do not know what is the percentage of concentration.)

Comment: False alarm, this was posted for my sister who made the mistake, and the way she phrased it made it sound like it was 3 ounces of bleach ( Found out it was Clorox) , while it was actually around a drop of bleach in around 6 ounces of water. Cleared it up with a emergency phone call w/ her boss.

Comment: I wouldnt say this is a false alarm at all - bleach ended up in a customers drink.  There are multiple issues here - what is an unmarked container containing bleach doing anywhere near a food prep area?  Given that a cleaning dilution of Clorox is 4 floz to 1 gallon, any amount in a slushy is going to be nasty - I seriously hope that 1. the solution in the container was already drastically diluted, and 2. the employer is taking action to prevent a repeat.

Comment: The restaurant is probably breaking some health regulation by storing bleach in a way and place it can be confused with water by _anyone_ (moreso by the staff, which would be expected to have been given proper training...).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the bleach, you could have just killed the customer, so why in hell are you worried about being sued (to which the answer is a solid “yes”, by the way)?  Most bleaches are a horrific poison for which there is little recourse once swallowed - it can easily result in death or permanent life altering injuries.

Being arrested for manslaughter or assault is a real likelihood here, both yourself and your manager.  Get legal advice, now.

Comment: Unless combined with some other chemical, bleach (sodium hypochlorite) isn't actually that toxic, it's corrosive nature is what makes it dangerous.  If it was present in deadly quantities in the slushy it would be immediately obvious when consumed, that is if the customer didn't notice the chlorine odour first.  In small quantities, like apparently was the case here, bleach can actually used to safely disinfect water to make it drinkable.

Comment: @RossRidge I shall defer to my wife on this topic, a doctor.  We do NOT know the quantities involved here, so the only safe recourse of action is to try and contact the customer and get them to seek medical attention - ingestion of bleach can have seriously long term harmful effects even in small quantities, and you seem to want to brush it under the proverbial rug...  Water purification is done with measured quantities at an extremely diluted level, while here you have someone adding an unknown quantity of an unknown dilution to someones drink.  Nowhere near the same thing.

Comment: The problem is that your answer assumes that a deadly or near deadly concentration of bleach must have been consumed. If so then the corrosive nature of bleach would have made this immediately obvious.

Comment: @RossRidge is it your opinion then that it is safe to drink any amount of bleach which is not immediately obvious as such for the consumer? I would be extremely cautious about concentration before thinking on _drinking_ it, and here we don't even have an idea about them!

Comment: @RossRidge no, not necessarily, there are plenty of complications that can occur from ingesting bleach throughout the digestive tract, not just from immediate corrosive damage.  And no, my answer does NOT assume a deadly or near deadly quantity was consumed, it makes the only assumption you should EVER make in this circumstance - that its a bad thing to do, and being worried about being *sued* is the last thing you should be doing.  There was NO thought about the customers health, and thats why my answer is as it is - stop worrying about being sued and start worrying about the customer.

Comment: @Ángel No, I'm only saying that a deadly amount like this answer claims must have been ingested would be immediately obvious.

Comment: A deadly amount would probably have already been found as a corpse. I can only be happy for that.

Comment: @RossRidge I cannot seriously believe you are defending the addition of any cleaning material at an unknown dilution and unknown quantity to someones drink - aside from the obvious issue with ingesting bleach, there are medical complications to consider here.  Handwave it away as a dislike of my answer all you want, but at the end of the day its indefensible - you never add unknown chemicals to someones drink and then shrug it off.

Comment: I'm not defending anything.